# Perl line length read

Tags: perl, line

In windows end of line is \r\n (x0dx0a)
For example (a 2 lines text) textfile.txt :

```
abc
def
```

I originally thought each line would be lenght == 5.
But when i tried the read function it seems we need to consider each line to have 3 + 1 chars (length == 4). counting the newline as 1 char (as x0a).

I was wondering is there a way to make perl read each octet of the file (read the x0d too)?

I am not sure it is usefull but i was just wondering ^_^

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[binmode](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html) on the input file handle.

Comment: or `'<:raw'` instead of `'<'`

Comment: But why would you *want* to do this?

Comment: me? I m migrating some Rexx code to perl, i would like to preserve the way they used to describe their line length for fixed length line text (for dos or unix file)